# FlashAttributes not in model after redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/notations")
public String listAll(Model model) {
    Iterable<PriceNotation> allItems = loadAllNotations();
    model.addAttribute("notations", allItems);
    return "supply/notations";
}
```

Then I have this method which redirects to the one above:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/notations/delete")
public String delete(@RequestParam(name="id", required=true) Long id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
    try {
        notationRepository.deleteById(id);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "delete failed");
    }
    return "redirect:/notations";
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in the first method after a redirect, the model is empty. Although the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) says:

> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the
>   model of the controller that serves the target URL.

Also in my html page I have this header which should display the message:

```
<h2 th:text="${message}"></h2>
```

Also this header is empty. What am I missing?

PS, I know this question has been asked before but there was no accepted answer and none of the suggestions worked for me.

Comment: Turns out my browser blocked cookies from localhost, which blocked this mvc feature. After allowing them, I can access the flash attributes after redirect.

Answer (score 0):

they are not added to model as they are passed as query parameters like `example.com?message=abc`.

So you can either:

- access them in controller with `@RequestParam` and then add to your model
- OR access them in thymeleaf with `${#param.message[0]}`

in summary you should treat `redirectAttributes` as reqular query parameters in receiving controller (listAll).

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. First, I cannot access them as you said. Second, the documentation explicitly mentions that FlashAttributes are automatically added to the model after a redirect.

Comment: Sorry, you were not completely wrong in your answer. What you mean, however, is RedirectAttributes.addAttribute(). These are added as RequestParameters. The FlashAttributes I was asking about are added to the model.